# Android how to close an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've created an intent using

```
browserIntent   =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
```

How do I close it?  Is it

```
browserIntent.close
```

or something... perhaps

```
browserIntent.finish();  ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot close another application's activities.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Your intent starts a new application - browser. You can not close that application (browser) from with your activity.

Workarounds:

1. You could however put you activity in front from a service (call intent on your activity). The question is based on what user activity would you do that, since you are not receiving user events in service.
2. If you need user to view some web sites, you could use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). This is basically embedded browser that you can control.

Comment: i am starting a browser intent from my activity, than i return to my activity from the browser, and then when i "fiinish" my activity with key_back button i will on the browser screen again, not on my main activity:( how to do this back?

Comment: "than i return to my activity from the browser," - how do you do that? With back button?

Answer (score 5):

You can't close an intent. An `Intent` is just what it says - an intent, i.e. something you would like to. An intent by itself doesn't do anything. You're probably refering to an activity, which is the result of calling `startActivity` on an `Intent`.

You can't close somebody else's activity. You can just start a new one.