# How to Close an Intent Activity from another Class

Tags: java, android

Basically I'm using the following code to open Google Navigation within an activity

```
 String uri = "google.navigation:ll="+LAT+","+LNG;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(i);
```

Where `LAT & LNG` are the coordinates of a specific destination. Basically what I'm trying to do is once the destination is reached, an action would be triggered where the navigation activity closes and return to the same Class it was opened in.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
i guess since the activity i opened "Google Navigation" is beyond my control it is impossible to close it from within the app. So the best solution would be to reopen the current activity once the destination is reached.

Appreciate all the answers.

Comment: once you are in Navigation activity how are u switching another activity.

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen what i want to do is close the navigation activity once the destination is reached.

Comment: maybe you can see this post 
[Android how to close an intent?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108446/android-how-to-close-an-intent

Comment: @TonyStark i guess this is the best solution, thanks alot.

Comment: use finish(); for the result

Answer (score 2):

Use finish() method to end the first activity

Answer (score 1):

use `Finish()` method to kill your activity as

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` method to end an activity

Comment: the problem is the 'finish' method can be used to close an activity after say you start another activity, but what I'm looking for is how do i finish the navigation activity from another activity

Answer (score 0):

Use finish() to kill the activity.

Comment: i think you miss understood my question, I'm not looking to close the current activity, i would like to close the activity i opened from the activity the i opened it in if that makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

Add `Finish()` method to end up an activity@

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: this would close the current activity, not the activity that was opened. My question was how do i close the opened activity from within the current activity

Comment: wanna close previous opened activity from current one, is it?

Comment: No, i want to close the navigation activity, which is opened from the current one. Problem is i can't access the navigation class as it is provided as is, so i must be able to close it from the class i opened the navigation activity in.

Answer (score 0):

If you press your  back button it will work !! don't finish() the previous activity.
Dont call finish() when you are starting the intent. Once you finish with navigation press back button

Comment: yes it does, but is there any method where it can be done programmatically?

Comment: @aasg yes you can do that too

Comment: can you provide me with a method that would do that?

Comment: did you try the proposed solution? You don't have to do anything, when the destination is reached, if you press back you will go back to your app (if you didn't call finish()).

Comment: @fasteque Actually i did try them before, but i would like the app to go back to the previous activity without pressing the back button

Comment: Google Navigation is not under your control, so unless it sends a broadcast message for which you can register a receiver to get a notification, you cannot do what you would like to do.

So check if a message is broadcasted or not.

Comment: @fasteque i guess reopening the current activity once the destination is reached is the best solution, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put a thread to compare the destination and current location.
Like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO: Do your work here
        myHandler.sendMessage(new Message());
    }
};
```

create a handler and implementing the handleMessage method.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO: finish the activity here
        finish();
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm already able to calculate the difference, but the problem i was facing was how to close the navigation activity once the location is reached

Comment: new a Handler and implements the handleMessage method, pass the handler to your class which is used to calculate the difference, once the location is reached send a message to this handler.